# How do automatically run a script after cvs update?

Tags: cvs, vcs-checkout

Everyday morning I update my local code using `cvs update`. The problem is that CVS stores my password. I usually type `cvs logout` from cmd in order not to use my user any more. This way I will prevent myself from accidental commits to CVS. Any ideas on how to log out automatically after running `cvs update`?

Comment: How often are you accidentally committing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CVS has pre and post-commit hooks. There is no update hook. https://priyamuthukumar.wordpress.com/tag/cvs-hooks/

The easiest way is to code a script which updates and then logs out.

Comment: Down-voted answer due to broken link. Here's another one that might be helpful: https://priyamuthukumar.wordpress.com/tag/cvs-hooks/